# website closing. forward all links to root, but allow images

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=301,L]
```

to send all requests back to the root of the domain to show a closing page.

This works fine but the images in the css file are not being loaded for some reason.

How can I allow the images to be loaded?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: a more useful comment would be to tell me where a more appropriate place to ask would be.

Comment: Questions about Apache configuration like this go on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). But don't repost this there; it will be migrated for you.

Comment: http://superuser.com/ or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ are more relevant.

Comment: @Basile: from what I've heard, [webmasters.SE] takes high-level questions about Apache configuration, but not specific questions about particular directives. In other words, Webmasters is for the "why" questions, Server Fault is for the "how".

Answer (score 1):

Try below Rule:

```
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ "destination page back to the root of the domain" [NC,L]
```

Please do required changes.

Comment: this is giving me a: "The page isn't redirecting properly" message.

Comment: Paste here your rule after changes by you

Comment: Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php [R=301,L]

Comment: remove "/" before index.php. and try

Comment: no joy, unfortunately. If the rule in original post allow the css to be loaded, I can't work out why the images are not being loaded..?